# Humbucker pickup wrapping wire role (The one that wraps the four wires together)

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups, wiring

I was wondering if this wrapping can be removed as it is very hard to stack all the wires so that the pickguard will be easily placed inside the guitar. Does it shield noises for the four wires coming from the pickup or is it just for packing nicely these wires ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrapping you are talking about is essential - it is there to screen the signal wires from electromagnetic interference, including mains hum, crosstalk, interference from signal processors, in fact any form of EM signal nearby.

Don't be tempted to remove it - you would actually be better off removing a little bit of wood from the guitar or placing the pickups a little higher if it really isn't fitting, however I have never made, repaired or seen a guitar where the wires couldn't be made to fit witha little judicious prodding.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure. It does fit in but I need to put a bit pressure to close it. Preferred otherwise but if the wrapping is essential than so be it. Thanks !